# How to aggregate and SUM EntityFramework fields with multiple joins

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, aggregate, grouping

I am able to produce a set of results that are desirable, but I have the need to group and sum of these fields and am struggling to understand how to approach this.

In my scenario, what would be the best way to get results that will:

1. Have a distinct [KeyCode] (right now I get many records, same KeyCode
   but different occupation details)
2. SUM wage and projection fields (in same query)

Here is my LINQ code:

```
private IQueryable<MyAbstractCustomOccupationInfoClass> GetMyAbstractCustomOccupationInfoClass(string[] regionNumbers)
{
    //Get a list of wage data
    var wages = _db.ProjectionAndWages
        .Join(
            _db.HWOLInformation,
            wages => wages.KeyCode,
            hwol => hwol.KeyCode,
            (wages, hwol) => new { wages, hwol }
        )
        .Where(o => regionNumbers.Contains(o.hwol.LocationID))
        .Where(o => o.wages.areaID.Equals("48"))
        .Where(o => regionNumbers.Contains(o.wages.RegionNumber.Substring(4))); //regions filter, remove first 4 characters (0000)

    //Join OccupationInfo table to wage data, for "full" output results
    var occupations = wages.Join(
                _db.OccupationInfo,
                o => o.wages.KeyCode,
                p => p.KeyCode,
                (p, o) => new MyAbstractCustomOccupationInfoClass
                {
                    KeyCode = o.KeyCode,
                    KeyTitle = o.KeyTitle,
                    CareerField = o.CareerField,
                    AverageAnnualOpeningsGrowth = p.wages.AverageAnnualOpeningsGrowth,
                    AverageAnnualOpeningsReplacement = p.wages.AverageAnnualOpeningsReplacement,
                    AverageAnnualOpeningsTotal = p.wages.AverageAnnualOpeningsTotal,
                });

    //TO-DO: How to Aggregate and Sum "occupations" list here & make the [KeyCode] Distinct ?

    return occupations;
}
```

I am unsure if I should perform the Grouping mechanism on the 2nd join? Or perform a .GroupJoin()? Or have a third query?

Comment: I think a `GroupJoin` would be useful. Is there multiple entries in `wages` for one entry in `OccupationInfo`?

Comment: @NetMage You are correct, there are multiple entries in wages for each OccupationInfo entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var occupations = _db.OccupationInfo.GroupJoin(
            wages,
            o => o.KeyCode,
            p => p.wages.KeyCode,
            (o, pg) => new MyAbstractCustomOccupationInfoClass {
                KeyCode = o.KeyCode,
                KeyTitle = o.KeyTitle,
                CareerField = o.CareerField,
                AverageAnnualOpeningsGrowth = pg.Sum(p => p.wages.AverageAnnualOpeningsGrowth),
                AverageAnnualOpeningsReplacement = pg.Sum(p => p.wages.AverageAnnualOpeningsReplacement),
                AverageAnnualOpeningsTotal = pg.Sum(p => p.wages.AverageAnnualOpeningsTotal),
            });
```

Comment: This is pretty wonderful but I am having trouble using .Sum() on any of the "hwol" fields.  pg.Sum(p => p.hwol.SomeIntegerField) is causing it to crash. Any idea how to get the hwol members to show up and not be null?

Comment: No, I don't see why that would be null. Are you using EF? You may be having `.Include` issues. Otherwise it appears to me the join should only produce non-null results.

Comment: Strange, it wanted the field to be defined "nullable". Now it works. Thanks so much for your help, this is awesome!! I couldn't quite figure out how to incorporate the .GroupJoin() correctly. Much appreciated.